# Understanding whether the addition of an element to a subgroup of an infinite group will result in an infinite group or not in GAP/SageMath

Tags: group-theory, gap, sagemath

This is more of a software-related question, but I wanted to ask here because I am confident that most people in this forum are well-acquainted with GAP/SageMath and can provide more insight for the answer.

Essentially, I have a subgroup of SU(2) known as SL(2,5). I took the tensor product of the matrix elements from this group with the identity to obtain 4x4 matrices. Then, I attempted to add a matrix that does not belong to this subgroup to the matrix group. Finally, I wanted to check whether this combination results in an infinite or finite group.

I specifically intended to achieve this using software. There are two main software options for these kinds of group theory processes, one of which is SageMath. I attempted to code something in SageMath, but it was unsuccessful. I'm wondering if someone can assist me with this. Additionally, I'm curious about other methods to prove whether the combination of a finite subgroup with a different element yields a finite or infinite group.

Here is my code in sagemath (and I am fine if someone has it in GAP too)

```
addition = matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]]) 
print(addition)
new_matrices_ = []
gens_ = MatrixGroup(SL(2,5)).gens() #the subgroup I am interested
print(len(gens_))
identity_mat = matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])#Identity(2)#matrix[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
for i in gens_:
        i_matrix_ = matrix(i)
        tensor_mat_= i.matrix().cross_product(identity_mat) #tried to tensor product of the group element with identity but can't achieve that
        #tensor_mat_ = i.kronecker_product(gens_[0]) #tried to tensor product of the group element with identity but can't achieve that
        #print(tensor_mat_)
        new_matrices_.append(tensor_mat_)
new_matrices_.append(addition)   
is_infinite(MatrixGroup(new_matrices))
```

I am stuck in the line that make a tensor product of the group element with identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
addition = matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]]) 
new_matrices_ = []
gens_ = MatrixGroup(SL(2,5)).gens() #the subgroup I am interested
for m in gens_:
    tensor_mat_= m.matrix().tensor_product(identity_matrix(2))
    new_matrices_.append(tensor_mat_)
```

Some elements:

```
new_matrices_[20:25]
```

returns

```
[
[2 0|2 0]  [1 0|4 0]  [1 0|1 0]  [3 0|3 0]  [1 0|3 0]
[0 2|0 2]  [0 1|0 4]  [0 1|0 1]  [0 3|0 3]  [0 1|0 3]
[---+---]  [---+---]  [---+---]  [---+---]  [---+---]
[3 0|1 0]  [4 0|2 0]  [1 0|2 0]  [2 0|4 0]  [0 0|1 0]
[0 3|0 1], [0 4|0 2], [0 1|0 2], [0 2|0 4], [0 0|0 1]
]
```

Now append `addition`:

```
sage: new_matrices_.append(addition)
sage: MatrixGroup(new_matrices_)
Matrix group over Finite Field of size 5 with 121 generators
sage: MatrixGroup(new_matrices_).is_finite()
True
sage: MatrixGroup(new_matrices_).cardinality()
18000000
```

Comment: I was just writing an answer to this question with cordinality :)

Comment: Careful: In GAP, `SL(2,5)` is defined over the field with 5 elements, which pushes everything into this characteristic, and in particular makes it finite. Since the OP writes $SU(2)$, I presume she wants groups in characteristic zero.

Comment: hmm, how to make characteristic zero? can you provide an example?

Comment: Can you describe complex matrix generators for $SL(2,5)$ as a subgroup of $SU(2)$? Or matrices over another characteristic zero field, like the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You will need a faithful, complex, 2-dimensional representation of $SL(2,5)$, and there seem to be two inequivalent ones: `g:=SL(2,5);irr:=Filtered(Irr(g),x->x[1]=2);gp:=List(IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(g,irr),Image);` produces two groups.

Comment: do you know the sagemath corresponds of these GAP lines? Can you provide in sagemath for me? @ahulpke

Comment: @j.doe no. I have no clue about sage, only GAP.

Comment: You can get part of the way with this: `G = SL(2,5); Ch = G.irreducible_characters()`. Then if you evaluate `[a.values()[0] for a in Ch]`, you can see the 0th entry in each character and see that two of them are equal to 2. Then `a, b = Ch[1], Ch[2]` will give you the relevant characters. I'm not sure how to then convert those to matrix groups in Sage. You could read the GAP documentation at https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap71.html to see if you can reconstruct their algorithm.

Comment: Thank you both. You really helped me a lot for this question!! I guess it is a good timing for stopping this question since the discussion part is going further and long (I am happy with it but for the other readers, I guess it is hard to follow up) and meet up on for other questions :))

Comment: @ahulpke I asked the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739419/how-to-make-characteristics-zero-in-gap I now know how to make characteristic zero but then I do not know how to make kronecker product with that. I converted code from sagemath to GAP. I will be glad if you could look at it :)